# Angularjs Currency filter, change currency dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I get the currency from the backend in a json object. 
When I try to show it using the currency filter what comes on screen is the currency code and not the actual currency.

I have used both the html binding method as well as the javascript method.

```
<span>{{smsData.smsAmount|currency:smsData.currencyCode}}<span>
```

The out put that i get is

```
&euro;1.00
```

when the expected out put is

€1.00

The same is true with using java script.

```
$scope.smsData.smsAmount = $filter('currency')($scope.smsData.smsAmount, $scope.smsData.currencyCode);
```

Please tell me how can i set the currency using parameters.

Comment: `<span>{{smsData.smsAmount | currency : smsData.currencyCode}}<span>`

Comment: @CodeHater Sorry i had put '=' by mistake. Edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: a fiddle would be helpful

Comment: @CodeHater here is a plucker. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ry4mkUVKTPCHFQqAD8kX?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An another solution:

```
<span ng-bind-html="smsData.smsAmount | currency:smsData.currencyCode"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution i found is something like this:

```
<span ng-bind-html='smsData.currencyCode'></span><span>{{smsData.smsAmount|currency:''}}<span>
```

Please if anybody has a better solution then tell me.

Comment: it works if you replace the parameter with the currency code: `{{smsData.smsAmount | currency : '&euro;'}}`. but fails if you pass in a scope variable. really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span>
   {{smsData.smsAmount| currency:"€"}}
</span>
```

Hope it helps..........!

Comment: not really. The problem is that i get the currency code from the backend. And need to bind it with a variable. Which means it can be $ or AU$ or ₹ etc